# How to convert 3gp audio file to mp3?

Tags: audio, mp3, 3gp

I have a 3gp audio file recorded with my Android cellphone.

I would like to convert it to mp3, preferably on Linux, but Windows also an option.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Whereas the accepted response is fine for a command-line solution, one could alternatively just use the simple and UI-based Gnome Sound Converter tool (http://soundconverter.org).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i in.3gp -c:a libmp3lame output.mp3
```

See also: [Encoding VBR (Variable Bit Rate) mp3 audio](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encoding%20VBR%20(Variable%20Bit%20Rate)%20mp3%20audio)

If you are on Ubuntu, you can install `avconv` instead of `ffmpeg`, since Ubuntu ships an outdated version of the latter.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using ffmpeg (well, winff). But the codecs were missing so I needed the instructions here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1117283.

Comment: I had "Unknown encoder 'mp3'". The solution is to change "-acodec mp3" by "-acodec libmp3lame".

Comment: If you get: 

*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.

Then use:
avconv -i in.3gp -acodec mp3 -ar 22050 -f wav out.mp3